# How to use applet on the browser

Tags: java, css, netbeans, applet

I am trying to put my code on the browser using applet,

Here's the code

**Tax**

```
public class Tax extends JApplet implements ActionListener{

private JTextField taxRate = new JTextField();
private JTextField computeTax = new JTextField();

private JButton compute;

public void init(){
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,5));

    taxRate.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    computeTax.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    computeTax.setEditable(false);

    p1.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Please Enter your tax"));
    p1.add(new JLabel("Your TaxRate"));

    p1.add(taxRate);
    p1.add(new JLabel("Tax Result"));
    p1.add(computeTax);

    JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    compute = new JButton("Compute Tax");
    compute.addActionListener(this);
    p2.add(compute);

    add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    double tax = Double.parseDouble(taxRate.getText());

        if(tax < 0) {
            computeTax.setText("Invalid input");
        } else if (tax >= 0) {
            if(tax < 6001) {
                tax = tax * 0.10;
            } else if (tax >= 6001 && tax <= 27950) {
                tax = tax * 0.15;
            } else if (tax >= 27951 && tax <= 67700) {
                tax = tax * 0.27;
            } else if (tax >= 67701 && tax <= 141250) {
                tax = tax * 0.30;
            } else if (tax >= 141251 && tax <= 307050) {
                tax = tax * 0.35;
            } else if (tax > 307051) {
                tax = tax * 0.386;
            }
        }

    computeTax.setText(Double.toString(tax));

}
```

}

The applet code show in netbean
[image]

**The code in notepad**
[image]

**The error appear in firefox**

[image]

**The files in the netbean folder**

[image]

I have no idea why I am getting this error? The firefox java is the newest version, but applet still doesn't appear. I heard someone said need to override the security, but I have no idea how to do that...

Do anyone know how to fix this?

Thank

Comment: There are no class files in you directory, the `.java` files need to be compiled

Comment: Also note, that google chrome for example will start to not support java applets anymore.

Comment: do you mean I need to change the Tax.class to Tax.java? I tried it but it didn't work and I am using firefox to run it

Comment: Did you actually compile the program? And did you put the resulting binary in the same directory as the HTML file? Also, `applet` is a very very old tag; it was replaced by `object` a long time ago.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson As a webdeveloper, you need to know about these things in case you need to do maintenance on an existing website.

Comment: @MrLister  I was not asking for speculation on the OP's reasons for requiring this, I was asking the **OP** why they required this.  *"As a webdeveloper, you need to know about these things in case you need to do maintenance on an existing website."*  No.  As a web developer, the best advice you could give the client is to remove the need for applets entirely.  Any site that won't work with Chrome or ..Microsoft's browser (whatever they are calling the next version) is sunk.  Soon neither browser will support applets **at all.**